# MYSQL vs SQLITE syntax difference .. every derived table must have an alias

Tags: mysql, sqlite

I am quite an amateur with SQL (I am a teacher rather than programmer) and have written some code which worked in SQLITE but does not work in MYSQL.  I have a table called 'scores' of student names, exercises and scores.  As well as returning the completed exercises, I also wish to return those which are not completed.  For this I used CROSS JOIN to generate all combinations of student and exercise.  In SQLITE this returned null values for students that had not completed a particular exercise, which is useful.

Using this code in MYSQL, it complains that "*Every derived table must have its own alias*"

I understand this means that a subquery must have an 'AS ...' term.  However, no matter where I add it, I still receive that error.  I have tried online SQL 'validators' to help me, but still no success.

Can anybody help improve my code please ?  Thank you

```
SELECT othertable.name , othertable.exercise, scores.score
from ((select distinct name from scores)
CROSS JOIN (select distinct exercise from scores)) AS othertable
left join scores
on(scores.name = othertable.name AND scores.exercise = othertable.exercise )
order by othertable.name, othertable.exercise
```

Comment: `(select distinct name from scores) AS alias_here`

Comment: Server must have the capability to refer to any column using its full name `db.table.column` in any point of the query, i.e. to specify table/subquery alias to any existing column in any point where this column is visible. In your code - the columns produced by 2 subqueries `(select distinct column from scores)` does not match this rule on the level of CROSS JOIN which combines them.

Comment: Thank you so much Alex and Akina

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is what the error says, in MySql you must set an alias for each subquery of your query.
But instead of aliasing the 2 cross joined subqueries and the result of their join, drop the parentheses of the subqueries and use 3 aliases:

```
SELECT n.name, e.exercise, s.score
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT name FROM scores) AS n
CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT exercise FROM scores) AS e
LEFT JOIN scores AS s
ON s.name = n.name AND s.exercise = e.exercise
ORDER BY n.name, e.exercise
```